# C# List<class> first 3 items to string using lambda expression

Tags: c#, properties, lambda

How would you write the method MySpecialFunction to accompany the following code to produce the output shown below?  I'd like to show the first three properties in a comma-separated list and then count the remaining items and report them as a number.  I'd like to specify the property with a lambda expression.  Your help is appreciated!

```
public class MyObject
{
  public Text1 {get; set;}
  public Text2 {get; set;}

  public MyObject(string text1, string text2)
  {
    Text1 = text1;
    Text2 = text2;
  }
}

public class Main()
{
  List<MyObject> myObjects = new List<MyObject>();
  myObjects.Add(new MyObject("sample11", "sample12");
  myObjects.Add(new MyObject("sample21", "sample22");
  myObjects.Add(new MyObject("sample31", "sample32");
  myObjects.Add(new MyObject("sample41", "sample42");
  myObjects.Add(new MyObject("sample51", "sample52");

  MySpecialFunction(myObjects, f => f.Text1); 
  MySpecialFunction(myObjects, f => f.Text2);
}
```

The output strings are:

> sample11, sample21, sample31, and 2 more.
>
> sample12, sample22, sample32, and 2 more.

Thanks!

Comment: Where is your code for `MySpecialFunction`? Did you try anything?

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like the code below:

```
public class StackOverflow_14944788
{
    private static void MySpecialFunction(IEnumerable<MyObject> list, Func<MyObject, string> selector, int count = 3)
    {
        string result = string.Join(", ", list.Take(count).Select(selector));
        int listSize = list.Count();
        if (listSize > count)
        {
            result += ", and " + (listSize - count) + " more.";
        }

        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }

    public class MyObject
    {
        public string Text1 { get; set; }
        public string Text2 { get; set; }

        public MyObject(string text1, string text2)
        {
            Text1 = text1;
            Text2 = text2;
        }
    }

    public static void Test()
    {
        List<MyObject> myObjects = new List<MyObject>();
        myObjects.Add(new MyObject("sample11", "sample12"));
        myObjects.Add(new MyObject("sample21", "sample22"));
        myObjects.Add(new MyObject("sample31", "sample32"));
        myObjects.Add(new MyObject("sample41", "sample42"));
        myObjects.Add(new MyObject("sample51", "sample52"));

        MySpecialFunction(myObjects, f => f.Text1);
        MySpecialFunction(myObjects, f => f.Text2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a generic version that will guard against exceptions and will safely handle the case when there are fewer than *maxCount* items in your collection. It also avoids multiple enumerations of `input`:

```
static string MySpecialFunction<T>(IEnumerable<T> input, Func<T, string> selector, int maxCount)
{
    if (input == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("input");

    if (selector == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("selector");

    if (maxCount <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("maxCount must be greater than 0.");

    var items = input.Select(selector).ToArray();
    if (items.Length < 1)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
    else if (items.Length == 1)
    {
        return items[0];
    }
    else
    {
         var joined = String.Join(", ", items, 0, Math.Min(items.Length, maxCount));
         if (items.Length > maxCount)
         {
              joined += String.Format(", and {0} more.", items.Length - maxCount);
         }
         return joined;
    }
}
```

You would use it like:

```
Console.WriteLine(MySpecialFunction(myObjects, o => o.Text1, 3));
```

Comment: @comecme: Whoops, that was a typo. I copied this solution from a VB.NET one I had.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ([see it run](http://ideone.com/l9owo0)):

```
static string MySpecialFunction(IEnumerable<string> items, int limit)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    bool delimit = false;
    int count = 0;

    foreach (var item in items) {
        if (limit == 0) {
            ++count;
        } else {
            if (delimit) {
                sb.Append(", ");
            }

            delimit = true;
            sb.Append(item);

            --limit;
        }
    }

    if (count != 0) {
        sb.Append(", and ");
        sb.Append(count);
        sb.Append(" more.");
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Then you'd execute it like this:

```
var summary = MySpecialFunction(myObjects.Select(i => i.Text1), 3);
```

Comment: Better yet, using String.Join(): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa904288(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: @PatBurke That requires an array as input.

Comment: luckily we have a ToArray() method

Comment: @PatBurke Indeed. That would be one option, if you don't care too much about performance.

Comment: @cdhowie An overload to `Join` accepting an `IEnumerable` was added with .NET 4.0, you would need to call `ToArray` in earlier versions.  Note that for a method such as this it is unlikely that the input sequence is large enough for `ToArray` to be expensive enough to matter.

Comment: @Servy Aha. That would be important to note; not everyone is on 4.0 yet.

Comment: @cdhowie It's been out for a while.  It's generally acceptable at this point to use it unless the OP specifically specifies that they need an older version, or to adapt your answer in the event that they later state an older required version.  .NET 4.5 is new enough that you generally can't assume it's being used unless the OP makes it clear that they are using it.

Answer (score 0):

```
private String MySpecialFunction<T>(IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, String> selector)
{
    var prefix = items.Take(3).Select(selector);
    var suffix = " and " + (items.Count() - 3) +" more.";
    return prefix + suffix;
}
```

Comment: You should likely add a check such that the suffix isn't added unless there are at least 4 items in the input sequence.

Comment: @Servy - I should also check for null arguments, but omitted it since it is an example.

Comment: Checking for null arguments only makes the function generate a more useful error in the event that the input is bad, not checking if the suffix should be added results in it giving improper output when the input is valid.  There's a significant difference between those two.

Comment: The point is that it is an example, and fits the narrow requirements of the question. I'm not here to do someone's work for them... any decent software programmer should note this if the requirements need it.

Comment: This is similar to what I ended up using:  'public static string ListOfPropertiesToString<T>(IEnumerable<T> list, Func<T, string> selector, int count = 3)
        {
            string result = string.Join(", ", list.Take(count).Select(selector));
            int listSize = list.Count();
            if (listSize > count)
            {
                result += ", and " + (listSize - count) + " more.";
            }

            return result;
        }'